# CSLoader not working with Windows phone 8

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocostudio

I am working in Cocos2d-x v3.3 and Cocostudio v2.0.6.

I followed the instructions to create and load files CSB. I built in Android and Windows Phone 8. But it works in Android and crash in Windows Phone 8.

I checked and found this line fails:

```
auto node = CSLoader::getInstance()->createNode("MainScene.csb");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Project Explorer folder, navigate to you c# project, then Assert folder. Make sure that:

1. csb file is added, and with path you pass to function.
2. goto csb file properties (right click->properties) and select "content" for Build Action.